# PHP - How to add a new string right at the bottom of a specific word in an array?

Tags: php

I have an array that keeps changing possition

```
$cars = array("Volvo", 
              "BMW", 
              "Toyota",
              "Bird",
              "Horse");
```

and I have a new string that I want to add below `BMW`

```
$newvar = "Cow";
```

I know I can use `array_splice()` but it doesn't look for the word `BMW` it can only add a new string at a specific line. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use array_search() to find the position of 'BMW', and then use that in an array_splice()

Comment: ^ -> manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 4):

You can use [array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the position of 'BMW', and then use that in an [array_splice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

```
$cars = array("Volvo", 
              "BMW", 
              "Toyota",
              "Bird",
              "Horse");
$newVar = "Cow";

array_splice(
    $cars, 
    array_search('BMW', $cars) +1, 
    0, 
    $newVar
);

var_dump($cars);
```

Comment: Really nice answer with the reference to the manual and the little explanation :) (Now I'm going to drink my British breakfast tea)

Comment: Thanks, what does `+` in `+1` do ?

Comment: The `+` in `+1` means `plus` or `add` as it does in any arithmetic.... you wanted the new entry placed _after_ the value you searched for (`BMW`) so we need to add one to get the position after  `BMW`... without that `+1` we'd be splicing the new value _before_ `BMW`

Comment: This is fine when you know every string literal in your array, but it won't work as a general solution. array_search() has a mixed (ugh) return type that will give false if the value's not found, so the +1 will coerce it to index 1, so if you search an array and don't find, it'll splice in your value as the 2nd element. You may want to check the index like `$idx = array_search('BMW', $cars); if ($idx === false) { $cars[] = $newVar; } else { array_splice(`.... etc.